# OOP & Syntax - Ex 43 - Learn Python the Hard Way

Tags: python, function, class, oop

I'm brand new to coding and a total noob. I've been really enjoying going through Zed Shaw's book "Learn Python 3 the Hard Way" -- but when I got to this exercise and OOP, suddenly everything stopped making sense.

I really need some help from someone more experienced about how to actually translate this code "into English" so I can follow what it's doing... and ideally figure out how to write code like this as well.

There's another similar post on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414219/learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-43) -- but I'm really hoping someone generous out there can dive a bit deeper with me and that this will also prove beneficial to other noobs out there struggling with OOP.

I've included my questions line-by-line... I think by far one of the most helpful things someone could do is go over the syntax of this code with me. I'm trying to think about it in terms of a sequence: (1) xyz is inputted (2) abc happens (3) efg is returned.... but there are too many nested relationships for me to parse it all out without someone's help who is more experienced.

```
class Scene(object):

  def enter(self):
      print("This scene is not yet configured.")
      print("Subclass it and implement enter().")
      exit(1)
```

Q1: These lines are here for debugging purposes only, correct?

```
class Engine(object):

  def __init__(self, scene_map):
      self.scene_map = scene_map
```

Q2: My trouble starts here with OOP. How can I intuitively understand "init" and how to use it? I think 'self' = 'a_game'... but what does this line self.scene_map = scene_map even do in the context of the rest of the code?

```
  def play(self):
      current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
      last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')
```

Q3: there's a lot happening in those 2 lines (the Map class is involved as well)... what is this really saying?

```
      while current_scene != last_scene:
          next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
          current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
```

Q4: I get the "while" part of this... but then I get confused by these next 2 lines "next_scene_name = ..." and "current_scene = ..." Like the lines from the play function, I would love to know how an expert coder reads this.

```
      current_scene.enter()
```

Q5: I believe this is the heart of the code that initiates the action... but how does this interact with the values that are returned at the end of each Scene (which presumably lead to the next scene)? Each scene just ends with " return 'xyz' " -- I don't understand how that's enough.

```
class CentralCorridor(Scene):

  def enter(self):
      # print story-line here...
      action = input("> ")

      if action == "xyz":
          return 'laser_weapon_armory'
      # rest omitted...

class LaserWeaponArmory(Scene):

  def enter(self):
      # action & choices go here...

  return 'xyz'

class Map(object):

  scenes = {
  'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
  'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
  # more...
  }

  def __init__(self, start_scene):
      self.start_scene = start_scene
```

See Q2...

```
  def next_scene(self, scene_name):
      val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
      return val
```

Q6: I understand that when this function is called, it returns the value of the key from scene['scene_name'] -- but what actually calls this next_scene function in the first place? And when the 'val' is returned, where is it going?

```
  def opening_scene(self):
      return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)
```

Q7: since a_map is defined as class Map with the parameter 'central_corridor', I get that this is saying "return self.next_scene('central_corridor')" ... but after that I'm lost again! What is this really translating to?

```
a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

These final lines I understand... but, again, as soon as I start plugging them back into the rest of the code, I get lost pretty quickly.

That's it! I know it's a lot -- and I understand if people want to downvote me for being a noob, but I truly want to understand OOP and it has been quite challenging for me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the Same problem while studying OOPS from **Learn Python the Hard Way** so I would suggest you to learn OOPS from **Interactive Python**.

```
http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Introduction/ObjectOrientedProgramminginPythonDefiningClasses.html
```

Once you are familiar with OOPS concepts, you can continue Learn Python the Hard Way. I hope it helps you. This isn't an answer to your question but I don't have enough rep to comment.